# How are complex conditions represented in decision table

Tags: logical-operators, rule-engine, binary-decision-diagram

I am trying to model a decision table template.

Why I understand for simple rules like

`(x>10 and y<10) print "red"` can be represented in a decision table with one row using two columns for conditions and one column for action.

```
+-----+-----+-------------+
|  X  |  Y  |   Action    |
+-----+-----+-------------+
| >10 | <10 | Print "red" |
+-----+-----+-------------+
```

How are conditions like

`((x>10 and y<10) or x>1) or z<5 and y>5 print "red"` represented in decision tables.

I assume the above big condition is represented in many rows where the combination of different mini conditions is true. with the same action part repeated. **Is there any method to reduce conditions like this to decision tables?**

However In that case The action is fired multiple rows. Where as we have only one action. Is there any column for grouping?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to give actions numbers, and reference them from decision tables. If an action has been fired during an evaluation run, subsequent firings are ignored.

Here is an example:

```
+-----+-----+-----+--------+
|  X  |  Y  |  Z  | Action |
+-----+-----+-----+--------+
| >10 | >10 |  -  |   1    |
+-----+-----+-----+--------+
| >10 | <10 |  -  |   2    |
+-----+-----+-----+--------+
| >50 |  -  |  -  |   2    |
+-----+-----+-----+--------+
|  -  |  -  |  >5 |   2    |
+-----+-----+-----+--------+
```

Action number corresponds to an action from this table:

```
+-----+--------------+
|  #  |   Action     |
+-----+--------------+
|  1  | Print "red"  |
+-----+--------------+
|  2  | Print "blue" |
+-----+--------------+
```

If action #2 is fired because `x>10 AND y<10`, it wouldn't fire again even if `x>50` or `z>5`.

Comment: Is this fit Drools decision table?